# How to use JQuery ui Slider in Pan Zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jquery-ui-slider, pan

I want to use custom range bar in Jquery.panzoom.js in image zoom function, but i can' t customize input range slider in html, so i use Jquery ui plugin for custom range slider, but i cant use it on panzoom plugin, please find my below code and help me fix this, where im wrong,

HTML

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Panzoom for jQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section id="auto-contain">

      <div class="panzoom-parent">
        <img class="panzoom" src="758024315509.png" width="800" height="350">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="zoom-in" style="visibility:hidden">Zoom In</button>
        <button class="zoom-out" style="visibility:hidden">Zoom Out</button>
      <input type="range" class="zoom-range" style="visibility:hidden">
        <button class="reset" style="visibility:hidden">Reset</button>
        <input type="hidden" id="InValueUI" value="0"/>
      </div>
      <button id="btnInc">+</button>
      <button id="btnDec">-</button>
      <button id="btnReset">Reset</button>
       <div id="slider"></div>
</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
 body { background: #F5FCFF; color: #333666; }
      section { text-align: center; margin: 50px 0; }
      .panzoom-parent { border: 2px solid #333; }
      .panzoom-parent .panzoom { border: 2px dashed #666; }
      .buttons { margin: 40px 0 0; }

        .ui-widget-content.ui-widget {
            border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
        }

        .ui-slider-vertical {
            width: 5px;
            height: 150px;
        }
         .ui-widget-header {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            background: #000;
            color: #333333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            cursor: default;
            -ms-touch-action: none;
            touch-action: none;
        }

        .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:focus {
            background: #cbcbcb;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid #cbcbcb
        }

        .ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
            left: -0.359em;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-bottom: -0.6em;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
            border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
            background: #ebebeb;
        }

        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
            margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            list-style-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
            padding: 8px 5px;
            border-bottom-color: #cbcbcb;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            font-size: 13px;
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 18px 0px -17px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 18px 0px -17px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
            box-shadow: 0px 18px 0px -17px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
        }

        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item:last-child {
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
        }

        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item:hover {
            background-color: #64a2bb;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        .ui-menu .ui-menu-item:hover .ui-state-active {
            color: #fff
        }

        .ui-state-active,
        .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
        .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
        a.ui-button:active,
        .ui-button:active,
        .ui-state-active.ui-button:hover {
            border: 0px solid #003eff;
            background: transparent;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #000;
        }

        .ui-state-hover,
        .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
        .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
        .ui-state-focus,
        .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
        .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
        .ui-button:hover,
        .ui-button:focus {
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            background: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #2b2b2b;
            outline: none;
        }
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
      $('#btnInc').click(function(){
    $('.zoom-in').click();
      });
      $('#btnDec').click(function(){
    $('.zoom-out').click();
      });
      $('#btnReset').click(function(){
    $('.reset').click();
      });
       $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = 0;
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: a,
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            change: function(event, ui) {
    //  $('#ere').text(ui.value);
      var ab = $('#InValueUI').val();
        //  alert(ui.value);
         // alert(ab);

    var _avalue= Math.ceil(ui.value / 16.66666666666667);

    /*
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: _avalue*16.66666666666667,
    }); */
            //alert(_avalue);



    if(_avalue > ab){
        $('.zoom-in').click();
     }
    else if(_avalue < ab){
        $('.zoom-out').click();
     }
      $('#InValueUI').val(_avalue);

        // alert(ui.value);
        //debugger;
        /*var $section = $('#auto-contain');
            $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
            $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
            $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
            $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
            $reset: $section.find(".reset"),
            startTransform: 'scale(2)',
             increment: 0.5,
            minScale: 1,
            contain: 'automatic'
        }).panzoom('zoom');
        */
            }

        });
       // alert(ui.value);

      //Jquery Pan Zoom 


         var $section = $('#auto-contain');
          $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
            $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
            $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
            $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
            $reset: $section.find(".reset"),
            startTransform: 'scale(1)',
            increment: 0.5,
            minScale: 1,
            contain: 'automatic'
          }).panzoom('zoom');

        });

      </script>
```

Plugin Used : Jquery, Jquery ui, Jquery.PanZoom.js

i will do something with this code, but i need more clear on this,
1. when click zoom in (+) button the range slider wants to increase,
2.if press reset button the slider goes to 0 position,
3. need to sync both sliders and control buttons

please help me to fix all this,

Please find below image what im done, 
[image: Zooming with Jquery UI Slider]